# Control child div css using parent div class

Tags: angularjs, html, css

I have a rectangular box that can call modal when clicked. Inside the box are labels and an expand icon.

```html
<div class="clickable-box" ng-click="openRetailerGraphDetails()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#g-retailer-purchases-graph">
        <div class="dashboardBox clearfix">
              <div class="pull-left dashboardBoxLabel purchases">
                   <h4 class="dashboardBoxLabeltext">
                          {{RetailerPurchases}} RETAILER PURCHASES
                    </h4>
                    <span class="dashboardBoxLabel2">
                           For the current month
                    </span>
              </div>
              <img class="pull-right expand-icon" src="themes/img/dashboard/expand.svg" />
         </div>
      </div>
```

I want to change the opacity of the expand icon inside img tag from 0 to 0.7 when the whole clickable box is hovered. How can I achieve it?

Edit: Here`s the css

```
.clickable-box {
    cursor: pointer;
 }

 #dashboard .expand-icon {
    width: 20px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    margin-bottom: -25px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:hover` pseudo class:

```
#dashboard .clickable-box:hover img.expand-icon {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Comment: Not working for me. I added more details to the question it might help you improve this answer.

Comment: where are you getting dashboard id from?

Comment: @chriscozzens the updated question, it's in the CSS there.

Comment: @chriscozzens the dashboard id is the id of the whole page. It was not included in the code I posted but you can get the idea by looking at the css code for expand-icon class :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.clickable-box:hover img {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Comment: Note that (almost) the same answer already posted, and your answer is missing the `expand-icon` class of the `img` tag.

Comment: Looks like he beat me by a minute! dang lol should work the same as well.  Cheers.

Comment: You are welcome to upvote my answer :) regarding "should work the same" - correct, however if in the future he will add another image there - that iamge will also get that opacity on hover (and he wanted this specifically for the icon).

Comment: Not working for me. I added more details to the question it might help you improve this answer.

Comment: Please provide more detail... context... why this works outside of a css snip

Answer (score 0):

```
img.pull-right.expand-icon:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

[**CODEPEN DEMO**](http://codepen.io/beraht/pen/NpMgbW)

Comment: Not working for me. I added more details to the question it might help you improve this answer.